# BigCommerce WebDAV Upload with PHP

Tags: php, curl, webdav, bigcommerce

I'm trying to copy a file to the BigCommerce store.com/dav/content folder. If I set the file size to zero, it will create an empty file, but if the file size is anything other than zero, it doesn't do anything. Also, if I try to copy a .php file, I get $fh = Sabre\DAV\Exception\Forbidden instead of $fh = Resource id #3.

```
<?php

$credentials = array(
  'username',
  'password',
);

$filename = 'copyme.txt';
$filepath = 'foo/' . $filename;
$filesize = filesize($filepath);
$fh = fopen($filepath, 'r');

$remoteUrl = 'https://store.com/dav/content/';

$ch = curl_init($remoteUrl . $filename);

// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remoteUrl . $filename);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, implode(':', $credentials));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $filesize);

curl_exec($ch);

fclose($fh);

?>
```

Comment: You cannot upload php, ruby, python, etc to WebDAV. If you want that file on a server, it can be a BigCommerce server.

Comment: @Alyss Ok, I was fooled by my WebDAV client. I thought I uploaded a .php file, but when I did a refresh it was gone. Any thoughts on the .txt file?

Comment: As long as you aren't trying to upload it to the root directory, the .txt file might go, but I believe we only support media file types, .html, .css, and .js in webdav.

Comment: @Alyss It does the same thing with an .html file. I was using a .txt file as to reduce it to its simplest form.

Comment: I will have to assume it is based on file location then. .html, css, and js may only be accepted in the template folder and other media can be placed into the content folder such as pdfs, mp4s, mp3s, and image files

Comment: @Alyss I have already tried putting it in dav/template/Panels and that didn't work. I wouldn't be posting this question on Stack Overflow if it were that easy.

Comment: if you are trying to put anything with server side code into webdav for a BC store, it won't work. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are having trouble with at this point.

Comment: @Alyss in the stencil theme, I want to upload a file to the content directory in big-commerce, is it possible? I am also getting the same error like if filesize is 0 it creates an empty file otherwise it does not upload, I can not upload any file, like image, js, text to that folder using php, I am able to create using other WebDAV clients.